# Call a javascript function (in ASPX) page from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript file (viewer.js) situated in **Scripts/viewer.js**
My **default.aspx** has a javascript functions that calls a c# function in the **default.aspx.cs** ( it sends a http webrequest)

Now I want to call from the viewer.js the function in default.aspx which calls the c# function.

How can I handle this in my viewer.js?

I need to do this because I work with 3D objects and the select event is on the viewer.js

When I select the 3D object it needs to call the function in default.aspx...

**Scripts/viewer.js**

```
function ClickPickItem(item) {

        $("#properties").show();
        /*Call function App() */
    }
```

**Default.aspx**

```
function App() {
     PageMethods.Connect(callback);
 }
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
     [WebMethod]
        public static string Connect()
        {
            string rsp = DigestAuthFixer.GrabResponse("http://<username>:<password>@nextbus.mxdata.co.uk/nextbuses/1.0/1");
... CODE TO MAKE HTTPWEBREQUEST

}
```

Sorry if I'm not clear enough

I don't see another option like this

What I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `viewer.js` is included in the `Default.aspx`'s html, after the declaration of `App`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/viewer.js"></script>
```

You should simply be able to invoke the function, assuming it was created within global scope (or the scope of the document).

```
function ClickPickItem(item) {

    $("#properties").show();
    App();
}
```